# How to import ".xls" in python

Tags: python-2.7

I need to import ".xls" in python.
Can you please give me an idea for this.I must need to import only a excel file not ".csv" file.Because csv file neglects a leading zero's in number.

Answer (score -1):

Here’s the code example:

```
import xlrd



def open_file(path):


    #Open and read an Excel file

    book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)

    print book.nsheets  # print number of sheets

    print book.sheet_names()  # print sheet names

    first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)   # get the first worksheet

    print first_sheet.row_values(0) # read a row

    cell = first_sheet.cell(0,0)    # read a cell

    print cell

    print cell.value

    # read a row slice

    print first_sheet.row_slice(rowx=0,

                                start_colx=0,

                                end_colx=2)
if __name__ == "__main__":

    path = "test.xls"

    open_file(path)
```